# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Но почти все смотрящие этот фильм слышали какие-то странные шумы.

Comment: Предложение странное. Шумы они слышали когда-то в детстве, или сейчас, во время просмотра фильма? Лучше либо "смотревшие ... слышали", либо "смотрящие ... слышат".

Comment: А какие возможные основания вы видите для запятой?

Comment: В каком месте, по вашему мнению?

Comment: Ясно же, что после "все" и после "фильма". И не так уж просто объяснить, почему их не надо. Причастный оборот после определяемого слова-с.

Answer (score 3):

Не нужна. Из Розенталя ( http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=274 ), см. п.4:

> Определительный оборот, стоящий после определительного, указательного
>   или притяжательного местоимения, тесно примыкает к нему и запятой **не**
>   отделяется:
>
> *Все опоздавшие на лекцию стояли в коридоре.*

Comment: Кажется, он примыкает настолько тесно, что частично или полностью входит в состав подлежащего. Кто стоял? «Все опоздавшие» или даже «все опоздавшие на лекцию». Определительным он будет, если мы скажем: «Все студенты, опоздавшие на лекцию, стояли в коридоре». Кто стоял? «Все студенты» стояли. Какие? «Опоздавшие на лекцию».

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется в виду, что все, кто смотрит этот фильм, слышат странные шумы, то запятая не нужна, поскольку, как я понимаю, подлежащее тут не просто «все», а «все смотрящие» или даже «все смотрящие этот фильм». Если запятые поставить, то получится, что говорится не о тех, кто смотрит, а о каких-то «всех», которые смотрят.

Answer (score 0):

Грамматика предложения представляется мне стилистически некорректной.

Запятую ставить нельзя, так как оборот тесно примыкает к местоимению.

Тогда ***все*** — это определение, а ***смотревшие*** —  субстантивированное причастие в роли подлежащего, но это слово самостоятельно (без дополнения) вряд ли употребляется, поэтому в нем сложно увидеть предметное значение. Для сравнения: все **опоздавшие** стояли в коридоре.

Поэтому лучше написать так: ***Но почти все, кто смотрел этот фильм, слышали какие-то странные шумы.***